# Git How to Recursively Delete Files and Folders?

Tags: git, repository

I accidentally uploaded my bin, classpath, and a couple other files to my git which I had previously soft deleted. What command can I use to go through all my commits and delete certain files from my remote files only, not local.

Answer (score 4):

See the explanation on [GitHub](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILES' --prune-empty -- --all
```

With `FILES` being the files you want to nuke. Use `-r` if you want to delete whole directories.

Comment: Is there a way to use the index-filter to modify files? .. or do you HAVE to use the tree-filter?

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: This seems to be pretty unrelated. Consider asking it as a new question. (No idea, I've never actually used the filter commands)

Comment: ok.. lol.. you answered pretty quickly for someone that never actually used the command ;)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359759/720999) for an in-depth explanation of how `git filter-branch ...` works.